# Java Synchronized method is not locking object

Tags: java

I wrote a java program to generate unique id for each row in a file. There could be multiple jobs running same program to get unique ids. This id has to be unique for each row in any file. I tried to achieve this by serializing value to a file. Since multiple jobs will be using this program I made the method synchronized. Code works fine for single job but when tried to run multiple jobs at same time synchronized method fails. Looks like method is called again on same object when there is one already running. Why is synchronized method not locking the object?

Below is the id generate code I wrote –

```
public class CreateId2 implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private long i;

public synchronized long idGenerate() {

    long k = this.generateId(this);
    return k;

}
private long generateId(CreateId2 id){

    long returnedVal = id.getI();
    try {
    returnedVal = id.readObject();
    //System.out.println("previous modiefiied returnedVal is" + returnedVal);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException  ex) {
        id.setI(200L); //start from 200 for the first time
        returnedVal=id.getI();
    } catch (Exception ex2) {
        ex2.printStackTrace();
    }
    returnedVal = returnedVal +1;
    id.setI(returnedVal);
    //System.out.println("returnedVal is " + returnedVal);
    try {
    id.saveObject(id);
    } catch (Exception ex3) {
        ex3.printStackTrace();

        }
    return returnedVal;
}

public void saveObject(CreateId2 id) throws IOException{
    //System.out.println("saving object " + id.getI());
    File savedFileName = new File("C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\tests\\test.ser");
    FileOutputStream savedOutput = new FileOutputStream(savedFileName);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(savedOutput);

    oos.writeObject(id);
    oos.flush();
    // close the writing.
    oos.close();
    //System.out.println("saved. value is " + id.getI());
}

public long readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    //System.out.println("read object is called. value is " + ci2.getI());

    File savedFileName = new File("C:\\Users\\sam\\Desktop\\tests\\test.ser");
    FileInputStream savedInput = new FileInputStream(savedFileName);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(savedInput);

    //long val = Long.parseLong(ois.readObject().toString());

    CreateId2 ci2 = (CreateId2) ois.readObject();
    //System.out.println("value of valtemp " + ci2.getI());
    long val = Long.valueOf(ci2.getI());

    ois.close();
    return val;
    // close the writing.

}

public  long getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(long i) {
    this.i = i;
    //CreateId2.i = i;
}

// setter methods

private static CreateId2 instance = null;
private CreateId2() { }
public static CreateId2 getInstance() {
   if (instance == null) {
       instance = new CreateId2();
   }
   return instance;
}

}
```

I m calling this method like this -

```
CreateId2 id = CreateId2.getInstance();
long j = id.idGenerate();
```

When I call this method simultaneously I get this below error. Also generated ids are not unique anymore.

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2806)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:704)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:830)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at helperPackage.CreateId2.readObject(CreateId2.java:66)
    at helperPackage.CreateId2.generateId(CreateId2.java:23)
    at textFile.RandomTest.main(RandomTest.java:18)
```

Comment: Synchronization does not cause `EOFExceptions`. Reading past end of stream causes `EOFExceptions`. This is a job for a database.

Comment: That is correct. But I get EOFExceptions only when I try to run jobs in parallel. For some reason I cant figure out why this exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`synchronized` works only for two classes synchronizing on the same object in the same JVM. If you have multiple instances of the monitor object, or are running in multiple JVMs, or under a batch processing system where each job gets its own classloader(s) then `synchronized` won't work. Use type-4 UUIDs, which are random 128-bit values and "guaranteed" to be unique.

(Guaranteed in the sense that a collision is unlikely to happen even if you generated 1 million UUIDs per second for the age of the universe)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am using same JVM. I tried to call method on same object by getting existing instance only but I may not doing it correctly. I tested it by opening two windows of eclipse instance and ran two loops one after another. What could be the problem here?

Comment: @SamH if you "open 2 eclipses... blah blah" then you are using 2 separate processes SO you are using 2 separate JVMs SO there will be no synchronization between them using `synchronized` keyword.

If you ask why, the answer is short: Because some variable you are using to synchronize on (lets call it a LOCK) are DIFFERENT OBJECTS - the runtime context is not share between those processes so LOCK1!=LOCK2.

Answer (score 0):

Jim Garrison has answered many situations may causes the issue. I want to add one more possible (and common) mistake could cause this issue:

*idGenerate()* is thread-safe, but your singleton constructor is not thread-safe. There's chance you create many *CreateId2* objects. See [an example of a thread-safe Singleton](http://crunchify.com/thread-safe-and-a-fast-singleton-implementation-in-java/)

Comment: I tried second option from the link (Auto ThreadSafe Singleton Pattern) but still same errors. Wrote this and extend this to test class -         public class ThreadSafeSingleton {
 private static final CreateId2 instance = new CreateId2();
  
 protected ThreadSafeSingleton() {
 }
 
 // Runtime initialization
 // By defualt ThreadSafe
 public static Object getInstance() {
  return instance;
 }

}